# Notepad++ :: Remove All Lines And Text That NOT Contains

Tags: text, ip, editor, notepad++

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

My regex is still not perfect but I need to solve 2 issues before I improve it...

I can get all lines with ip:port but I don't know how to :

1. remove the rest of the text WITHIN that line.
2. Replace the empty lines \r\n\ with nothing AT THE SAME REGEX REQUEST.

That a sample of text file :

```
junk text junk text junk text junk text junk text junk text junk text 
junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text junk text junk text junk text junk text 
junk text junk text junk text junk 127.0.0.1:28text junk text 
junk text junk text junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text 
junk text junk text junk text 
junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text 
junk text 
junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text 
junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text junk text 
junk text junk text junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text 
junk text junk text junk text junk text junk text 
junk text junk text junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text junk text junk text 
junk text junk text 127.0.0.1:28 junk text junk text junk text junk text junk text
```

I'm expecting to get back :

```
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
127.0.0.1:28
```

Obviously that example uses that same ip:port line but I don't want it to be fixed value.

Is it possible to do it with 1 single regex request?

...Just as a starting point I tried :

```
^(?!.*[09].*).+$
```

Comment: You might try [`(?s)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+)|(?:(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+).)*`](https://regex101.com/r/5DYpc9/1) and replace with `(?{1}$1\n:)` in Notepad++.

Comment: I need to do that in reverse : \b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d{1,5}\b

Comment: You may use your own IP regex pattern instead of `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+`. The technique is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and capture an IP with `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+)` and then you may match any text that does not start an IP like substring with a `(?:(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+).)*` [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

**Find What**: `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+)|(?:(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+).)*`

If you  add `(?s)` at the pattern start, you will not have to check the *`.` matches newlines* option.

To replace with just the IPs found and adding the line break can be done using a conditional replacement pattern:

```
(?{1}$1\n:)
```

It will replace the match with Group 1 value (IP) if it matched + a line break, else, the match will  be replaced with an empty string.

[image]